# Django - Field lookups LTE Not Working Correctly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I’m currently building a gaming app where logged in users have access to play different games based on their rank in our application.

If a currently logged in user has a `rank` of lets say `500` than all the games with a `game_rank` of `500` and below will be displayed. The rest of the games will be locked.

I tested with a user set to a `rank` of `500` but for some reason certain games below `500` are locked when they should be unlocked.

What’s going on with my current code that I’m missing to make this work correctly?

In my views I'm using `When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True))` which is working but not fully like how I would like.

The `rank` field in the `User_Info` model is for logged in users `rank`.

The `game_rank` field in the `Game_Info` model is for the games.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

**models.py**

```
class Game_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    game_rank = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    game_image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='game_covers', null=True, blank=True)
    featured_game = models.BooleanField(default=0)

class User_Info(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/profile_pics/default.png', upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=1)    
    user_games_enabled = models.ManyToManyField(Game_Info, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'unlocked_game': True})
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField


def account_view_home(request):
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    user_profile_rank = User_Info.rank
    user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.all()
    user = request.user


    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile = User_Info.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        user_profile_game_obj = User_Info.objects.get(user=request.user)
        user_profile_rank = int(user_profile_game_obj.rank)

        user_profile_games = Game_Info.objects.annotate(
            user_unlocked_game=Case(
                When(game_rank__lte=user_profile_rank, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )


        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games' : user_profile_games
        }

    else:
        context = {
            'user_profile': user_profile,
            'user_profile_games' : user_profile_games
       }

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
            {% for content in user_profile_games %}
            {% if content.featured_game == True %}
            {% if content.user_unlocked_game %}
            <!-- unlocked games logic -->

            <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                <div class="image-wrapper" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                    <span class="material-icons play_btn">play_circle_filled</span>
                    <img class="game-art" src="{{content.game_image.url }}" />
                </div>
            </a>
            <p class="game-title">{{ content.game_title }}</p>

            {% else %}
            <!-- locked games logic -->

            <a class="game-tile-container" href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">
                <div class="locked_game" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                    <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img class="game-art" src="{{content.game_image.url }}" /> 
                        <img class="lock-img" src={% static 'images/treasure-chest-closed-alt.png' %} />
                        <button class="level-up">Reach level {{ content.game_rank }} to unlock</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <p class="game-title">{{ content.game_title }}</p>

            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Use IntegerField for integer comparison, string comparison '9'  > '500'

Comment: @iklinac so should I make both ``game_rank`` and ``rank`` fields integer fields?

Comment: as they store integers yes, you should always have proper field type in DB